# Flask App: Managing external static files (e.g. js libraries, bootstrap)

Tags: python, flask, static-libraries

What is the proper way of managing external static files used in the project?

Currently I just manually download required libraries (e.g. bootstrap), put them into static directory and they become part of my repository. I am afraid that it is not the best strategy.

Is there any way to automate this process to work like e.g. pip?

Answer (score 0):

You are right putting your statics files under a  static folder  is the best practice according to Flask officials documentation.

But if you are looking for an external library for that use [flask asset](http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/static.html)